# onRadioButtonClicked(view) cannot resolve symbol + toasting ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, view, toast

I'm trying to write an application that adds strings to array lists based on which radio buttons are checked. Then, when the submit button is pressed, I want to toast every value within the array to check if it is reading the values properly.

Currently, when I try to call my `onRadioButtonClicked` method, I get the error:

**cannot resolve symbol "view"**

The error im getting from my toast is:

**cannot resolve method "makeText"**

---

Here is my code:

```
public class Availability extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> ava = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_availability);

        onRadioButtonClicked(view);

        Button sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AvaSubBtnId);
        sub.isClickable();
        if (sub.isPressed()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, ava, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.MonAMRadId:
            if (checked) {
                String monam = "Monday Am";
                ava.add(monam);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can't toast whole list , you must get each item of list and check the value you can do like this

```
Toast.makeText(this, ava.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```